# Accessing values for each key within a powershell hash table

Tags: powershell

I am looking at the item of using a hash table as a look up table within powershell.

In its most simple form, its something similar to the examples below.

Example 1

```
$hashTable = @{
    Key1 = 'Value1'
    Key2 = 'Value2'
}

foreach($key in $hashTable.Keys)
{
    $value = $hashTable.$key
    Write-Output "$key : $value"
}
```

Example 2

```
$ageList = @{}
$key = 'Kevin'
$value = 36
$ageList.add( $key, $value )
$ageList.add( 'Alex', 9 )



foreach($key in $ageList.keys)
{
    $message = '{0} is {1} years old' -f $key, $ageList[$key]
    Write-Output $message
}
```

I have defined a multi key hash similar to the below, which is slightly more complex when compared to the examples above.

```
$x = (1,"Server1",3,1),(4,"Server2",6,2),(3,"Server3",4,3)
$k = 'serverid','servername','locationid','appid'    # key names correspond to data positions in each array in $x
$h = @{}
  
  
For($i=0;$i -lt $x[0].length; $i++){
    $x |
        ForEach-Object{
            [array]$h.($k[$i]) += [string]$_[$i]
        }
           
           
} 

 $all_server_ids = $h['Serverid']


foreach ($server_id in $all_server_ids)
{
   $message = 'ServerID {0} has a servername of  {1}' -f $server_id, $h[$server_id]
    write-output $message

}
```

From what I have read, I understand that I can use the serverid as a key to access the other values.
When I run the above, what I get is this.

```
ServerID 1 has a servername of  
ServerID 4 has a servername of  
ServerID 3 has a servername of
```

On further research, I tried to use GetEnumerator, like the example below. Its not what I am trying to achieve.

```
 $h.GetEnumerator() | % { $_.Value }
```

The reason why I want to use a foreach is so that later on I can add parallel workflows to speed up the process, when the loop runs. I hope there are no issues with this approach.

I am also open to the idea of creating a custom object if this will work, what it needs is to be able to pass an array to it like the below to create custom objects and looping through each item using a foreach.

```
$x = (1,"Server1",3,1),(4,"Server2",6,2),(3,"Server3",4,3)
```

Comment: Named keys are in hash tables rather than arrays, which use positional indexes. To make this one example work you need to access the index position of the servername array that corresponds to the position of each serverid -> `$message = 'ServerID {0} has a servername of  {1}' -f $server_id, $h["servername"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_id)]`

Comment: Thanks very the very useful explanation and solution. How about storing in specific variables.     `$severid = {0} -f $server_id
    $servername = {1} -f $h["servername"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_id)]
    $locationid = {2} -f $h["locationid"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_id)]`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AdminOfThings

Here is the solution to the issue.

```
 $x = (1,"Server1",3,1),(4,"Server2",6,2),(3,"Server3",4,3)
$k = 'serverid','servername','locationid','appid'    # key names correspond to data positions in each array in $x
$h = @{}
  
  
For($i=0;$i -lt $x[0].length; $i++){
    $x |
        ForEach-Object{
            [array]$h.($k[$i]) += [string]$_[$i]
        }
           
           
} 


 $all_server_ids = $h['Serverid']

foreach ($server_id in $all_server_ids)
{
    $severid = $h["serverid"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_id)]
    $servername =  $h["servername"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_id)]
    $locationid =  $h["locationid"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_id)]

    $message = 'ServerID {0} has a servername of  {1} and a location id of {2}'  -f $server_id, $h["servername"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_id)],$h["locationid"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_id)]
    Write-Output $message
    Write-Output "This $severid and this $servername and this $locationid"

}
```

Now its possible to access keys and values as named.

Answer (score 0):

Other possibility 1 :

```
 #create your data
 $Datas = (1,"Server1",3,1),(4,"Server2",6,2),(3,"Server3",4,3)

 #create your objects
 $Objects= $Datas  | %{

     $Items=$_ -split ','

     [pscustomobject]@{
     serverid= $Items[0]
     servername= $Items[1]
     locationid= $Items[2]
     appid= $Items[3]
                    }
}

#use your objects
 $Objects| %{
'ServerID {0} has a servername of  {1} and a location id of {2}'  -f $_.serverid, $_.servername,$_.locationid
"This {0} and this {1} and this {2}" -f $_.serverid, $_.servername,$_.locationid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other possibility, with class (more elegant for me)

```
class ServerApp
 {
     [int] $serverid
     [string] $servername
     [int] $locationid
     [int] $appid

     ServerApp([int] $Pserverid, [string] $Pservername, [int] $Plocationid, [int] $Pappid ) {
     $this.serverid=$Pserverid
     $this.servername=$Pservername
     $this.locationid=$Plocationid
     $this.appid=$Pappid
    }
 }

 #create your data
 $Objects=@()
 $Objects+=[ServerApp]::new(1,"Server1",3,1)
 $Objects+=[ServerApp]::new(4,"Server2",6,2)
 $Objects+=[ServerApp]::new(3,"Server3",4,3)

#use your objects
 $Objects| %{
'ServerID {0} has a servername of  {1} and a location id of {2}'  -f $_.serverid, $_.servername,$_.locationid
"This {0} and this {1} and this {2}" -f $_.serverid, $_.servername,$_.locationid
}
```